# MySQL Bug - invalid attempt to access a field before calling read()

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've searched everywhere and i still can't figure out this one. Every time i open the form this error comes up but the program keeps runing without any problems. I have already figured out that the error is because i added a feature to the program. When i select the vehicle id code from the combobox, the text box automaticaly shows the vehicle name. That's the origin of the error.

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

```
    Try
        strsql = "SELECT nome FROM funcionarios where codfunc = " & Val(ComboBox1.Text) & ""
        comando.CommandText = strsql
        result = comando.ExecuteReader
        bs.DataSource = result
        tboxfunc.Text = bs.Current(0)
    Catch erro As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(erro.Message, "Erro do MySQL:",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    Catch erro As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(erro.Message, "Erro da Aplicação:",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try
    result.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Your not calling read, that's your issue and this could use a lot of help as well.

Comment: How and where do i call read?

Comment: After your result ... You would do something like: result.Read()

Comment: It's also a good practice to accept other answers as well. Not accepting answers from users helping you out wont get you much good help here, just a thought...

Comment: Thanks! I haven't refused any answers...